# ciclos php com base de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com problema em termos de lógica talvez.

Então é o seguinte:

```
                            $secao="select distinct seccao from foto";
                            $manda=  mysqli_query($ligacao, $secao);
                            $array_sec=array();
                            while (($recebe=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($manda))!=null){
                                array_push($array_sec, $recebe["seccao"]);
                            }
                            $re=count($array_sec);


$sql = "select imagem, seccao from foto order by seccao desc";
                            $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql);

                            for($i=0; $i<$re; $i++){
                                echo '<ul>';
                                while (($registo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) != null) {
                                    if($registo["seccao"]==$array_sec[$i]){ 
                                        echo "<li><a href=\"img/galeria/".$registo["seccao"]."/" . $registo["imagem"] . "\" data-smoothzoom=\"group1\"><img src=\"img/galeria/".$registo["seccao"]."/" . $registo["imagem"] . "\" width='188' height='119'></a></li>";
                                     }   
                                }
                                echo '</ul>';
                            }
```

Na primeira query eu vou buscar as secções ou categorias e armazeno-as num array, faço o count para saber o tamanho dele.
Depois faço a segunda query que é para ir buscar todas as imagens e suas respetivas secções.

Por fim faço um ciclo for em que percorre o tamanho do array que eu medi usando o count e depois faço o while em que vai percorrer todas as imagens recebidas pela segunda query. Faço uma verificação para ver se a secção do for é igual à secção do ciclo while ou seja da imagem, o problema aqui é que o primeiro `<ul>` faz bem, mas depois o resto não.

O objetivo era meter todas as imagens de cada secção num `<ul>` diferente.

Comment: Felipe, qual o erro? A consulta funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema do seu código é que você não guarda num `array` o resultado da segunda query, você faz o `mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)` durante o `while` e depois que acaba o primeiro `for` seu $resultado vai estar vazio.

Pra evitar isso é só você guardar num array parecido com o primeiro:

```
$array_segunda_query = array();
while ($array = mysql_fetch_row($resultado)) {
    $array_segunda_query[] = $array;
}
```

E depois você faz **DOIS** `for` de acordo com o tamanho de cada um

```
for($i=0; $i<count($array_sec); $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<$count($array_segunda_query); $j++){
         //seu codigo
    }
}
```

---

Mas eu acredito que da pra fazer tudo em 1 único `SELECT` e **for**.

```
$sql = "select imagem, seccao from foto order by seccao desc";
$resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql);

$atualUl = "";
while (($registo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) != null) {

    // precisa criar nova tag
    if ($registo["seccao"] != $atualUl) {

        // precisa fechar a tag anterior
        if ($atualUl != "") {
            echo '</ul>';
        }

        // criando a tag
        echo '<ul>';

        // atualiza o atual
        $atualUl = $registo["seccao"];
    }
    echo "<li><a href=\"img/galeria/".$registo["seccao"]."/" . $registo["imagem"] . "\" data-smoothzoom=\"group1\"><img src=\"img/galeria/".$registo["seccao"]."/" . $registo["imagem"] . "\" width='188' height='119'></a></li>";

}
// fecha ultima tag
echo '</ul>';
```

### [Exemplo IdeOne](http://ideone.com/gQ9Ym2)